# How to set relative position (oCoords) in FabricJs?

Tags: fabricjs

I have a Text in fabricJs. I set top and left.
This sets the aCoords properly to those values.
However the oCoords dont match. And the Text is not displayed at the right position.

I suspect that I need to set to oCoords somehow. So that the Text is displayed at the right pixel coordinates (top & left) on the canvas.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to set the Text at the pixel-coordinates on the canvas via fabricJs.

Comment: Its not clear, what you are asking, can you make a snippet explaining your issue?

Comment: `var fabricText = new fabric.Text({ "Hello", top: 100, left: 300 }); fabricCanvas.add(fabricText); fabricCanvas.renderAll();` The text is not displayed at pixel (x,y)-position (300,100) on the scaled canvas. But somewhere else. How to achieve now that the text is displayed at the exact pixel coordinates on the canvas?

Comment: Make a code snippet in your question. [check](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have checked the fabricText-object in the debugger. It seems that the aCoords are set to (300, 100) but the oCoords are sthg else.

Comment: How can it be that aCoords and oCoords are not in sync?

Comment: check [this](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#aCoords)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know maybe how I can set the position to the pixel position on the canvas independently from the zoom level which is applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aCoords and oCoords are two different things and should not be in sync.

In your comment you speak about scaled canvas.

Top and Left are 2 absolute values that represent the position of the object on the canvas. This position match with the canvas pixels when the canvas has a identity transform matrix.

If you apply a zoom, this coordinates diverge.

To get the position of pixel 300,100 of the scaled canvas on the unscaled  canvas, you need to apply some basic math.

1) get the transform applied to the canvas

```
canvas.viewportTransform
```

2) invert it

```
var iM = fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform)
```

3) multiply the wanted point by this matrix

```
var point = new fabric.Point(myX, myY);
var transformedPoint = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, iM)
```

4) set the object at that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work. :) Helped me a lot. So this calculation will transform oCoords (displayed Coordinates) to aCoords.

Comment: How do you come to know fabricJs so well btw. I find the tutorial not very comprehensive. Dont know how internally matrices are used in fabricJs.

Comment: Internally matrices are used to change between stages of transformations, that is a normal thing for 2d graphic, and sometimes the only way to do things since when different transform are applied ( scale, rotate, translate, skew ) is not possible to apply easy logic to them ( like left * scaleX for example ).

Comment: This calculation transform a relative point on the canvas to an absolute point on the NON TRANSFORMED CANVAS. so you count x,y from top left corner of the canvas element, and you get the point that match this one when the canvas has no zoom and no panning.

Comment: I know fabricjs good because i m the mantainer/developer actually.

Comment: This solution needs to get more prominence as I have seen the question asked many times (both for relative panning or zooming).