# How can I obtain the original coordinates from the activeObjects[] elements of a multiple selection?

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I am coding a web page using Fabricjs. First of all, I draw some circles in my canvas, then I allow the user to select one or more of them. I wrote a selection:created handler that creates a form and prints the coordinates of each selected object in that form.
The problem is that those coordinates are completely different from the ones I set when I created the circles. However, this happens only when the user select two or more circle.

What I basically do is: I call the getActiveObjects() method that returns an activeObjects[] array, then I loop to access the left and top properties of each element of that array. I have also tried to make same manipulation of those numbers as this answer suggests: [How to set relative position (oCoords) in FabricJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794187/how-to-set-relative-position-ocoords-in-fabricjs/45812109#45812109)

This is how I create circles:

```
function drawCircle( x, y, r, color ){
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: r, fill: color, originX: 'center', originY: 'center', left: x, top: y, lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true, hasControls: false});
    canvas.add(circle);
}
```

And this is the selection:created handler:

```
canvas.on('selection:created', function(e){
    var activeObjects = canvas.getActiveObjects();
    var length = activeObjects.length;
    var myForm = document.createElement("form");

    for( var i=0; i<length; i++){                   
        var x = document.createElement("input");
        x.setAttribute('type',"text");
        x.setAttribute('name', "x"+i);
        x.setAttribute('value', activeObjects[i].left);

        var y = document.createElement("input");
        y.setAttribute('type',"text");
        y.setAttribute('name', "y"+i);
        y.setAttribute('value', activeObjects[i].top );

        var radius = document.createElement("input");
        radius.setAttribute('type',"text");
        radius.setAttribute('name', "radius"+i);
        radius.setAttribute('value', activeObjects[i].radius );

        f.appendChild(radius);
        f.appendChild(x);
        f.appendChild(y);                   
    }
})
```

I expect that if I create two circles calling drawCircle(10,20,2,'black') and drawCircle(30,30,2,'black') and I select them, I will read in the form the values 10, 20, 2, 30, 30 and 2; instead, only the radius values are correct, but the coordinates are respectively (-10, 395) and (10, 405). As you can see, the distance between the two circle is still the same, but their coordinates are completely different from the original.
Moreover, if I modify the selection (let's say I select 3 circles), in the form I will read other completely different values.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

fabric.Group.prototype.lockMovementX = true;
fabric.Group.prototype.lockMovementY = true;
fabric.Group.prototype.hasControls = false;

var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 2, fill: 'black', originX: 'center', originY: 'center', left: 10, top: 400-20, lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true, hasControls: false});
canvas.add(circle);

var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 2, fill: 'black', originX: 'center', originY: 'center', left: 30, top: 400-30, lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true, hasControls: false});
canvas.add(circle);

canvas.on('selection:created', function(e){
  var activeObjects = canvas.getActiveObjects();
  var length = activeObjects.length;
  
  var activeSelection = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var matrix = activeSelection.calcTransformMatrix();
  
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  
  for( var i=0; i<length; i++){
    var obj = activeObjects[i];
    var objectPosition = { x: obj.left, y: obj.top };
    var finalPosition = fabric.util.transformPoint(objectPosition, matrix);                       

      var radius = document.createElement("input");
      radius.setAttribute('type',"text");
      radius.setAttribute('name', "raggio"+i);
      radius.setAttribute('value', obj.radius );
      
      var x = document.createElement("input");
      x.setAttribute('type',"text");
      x.setAttribute('name', "x"+i);
      x.setAttribute('value', finalPosition.x );

      var y = document.createElement("input");
      y.setAttribute('type',"text");
      y.setAttribute('name', "y"+i);
      y.setAttribute('value', 400-finalPosition.y );

      form.appendChild(radius);
      form.appendChild(x);
      form.appendChild(y);
     }     

     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(form);     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.min.js"></script>


<h1> Grid </h1>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to take in consideration the transform of the object that is applied by the group.
When you just make the selection you may think there are no transformation, but fabricjs is drawing those circles around the center of the selection, there is a translate operation.

A way to solve it generally for any transform ( scale, rotate, ) is:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

fabric.Group.prototype.lockMovementX = true;
fabric.Group.prototype.lockMovementY = true;
fabric.Group.prototype.hasControls = false;

var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 2, fill: 'black', originX: 'center', originY: 'center', left: 10, top: 20, lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true, hasControls: false});
canvas.add(circle);

var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius: 2, fill: 'black', originX: 'center', originY: 'center', left: 30, top: 30, lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true, hasControls: false});
canvas.add(circle);

canvas.on('selection:created', function(e){
  var activeObjects = canvas.getActiveObjects();
  var length = activeObjects.length;
  
  var activeSelection = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var matrix = activeSelection.calcTransformMatrix();
  
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  
  for( var i=0; i<length; i++){
    var obj = activeObjects[i];
    var objectPosition = { x: obj.left, y: obj.top };
    var finalPosition = fabric.util.transformPoint(objectPosition, matrix);                       

      var radius = document.createElement("input");
      radius.setAttribute('type',"text");
      radius.setAttribute('name', "raggio"+i);
      radius.setAttribute('value', obj.radius );
      
      var x = document.createElement("input");
      x.setAttribute('type',"text");
      x.setAttribute('name', "x"+i);
      x.setAttribute('value', finalPosition.x );

      var y = document.createElement("input");
      y.setAttribute('type',"text");
      y.setAttribute('name', "y"+i);
      y.setAttribute('value', finalPosition.y );

      form.appendChild(radius);
      form.appendChild(x);
      form.appendChild(y);
     }     

     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(form);     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.min.js"></script>


<h1> Grid </h1>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border: 1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Loos pretty solid to me now that i updated my answer with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does not work and now the output is wrong even for a single selection: the circle with coordinates (10,20) becomes (20,-360). Instead the radius is still correct (2px).

Comment: You should make your question active inserting the `stackoverflow snippet` would make easier to verify it.

Comment: Ok I did not notice you modified the answer! Now, with `activeSelection.calcTransformMatrix()` works for more than one selected object. Instead, if `length==1' I did not use the transform matrix. Thank you!