# Find original (x,y) new coordinates in fabric canvas

Tags: fabricjs

I am building a Warehouse map in 2D with fabricjs where I am displaying their racking systems as a series of rectangles.

As a first "layer/group", i add all bays as groups containing a rectangle and text, both positioned at the same (x,y). They also have both an angle set to fit their orientation in the space.

As a second "layer/group", i add groups containing a circle and text, representing the bay's number of issues. The (x,y) also fits the bays. This way, all my issues are always on top of the bays and the center of the group fits the rotated corner of the bay.

On the first paint, all is well aligned. Once they're shown on the page, the user can create new issues, so I am trying to position the issue group fitting the original (x,y), but since it can all be panned and zoomed, I am having a hard time positioning it where it should be.

I've been looking at their explanations about [transforms](http://fabricjs.com/using-transformations), but I can't figure who the boss should be and thinking that having nested groups may also be why I am all mixed up.

By doing:

```
const gMatrix = matchingBay.group.calcTransformMatrix(false);
const targetToCanvas = fabric.util.transformPoint(matchingBay.aCoords.tl, gMatrix);
```

I am on the bay, but on the "group" corner, which is not what I am looking for. (x,y) will be one of the corners of the rectangle in the group, that may have been rotated.

By specifying the original (x,y) in this code will get me way off the actual painting zone.

So, my question is, how do I get the transformed (x,y) so I can add my issue group at those coordinates?

[EDIT]

As the suggestion of spring, it made me realize I can use the rotated rectangle's transforms to find its coordinates, so I tried:

```
const rect = matchingBay.getObjects()[BAY_RECTANGLE_INX];
const gMatrix = rect.calcTransformMatrix();
const targetToCanvas = fabric.util.transformPoint(rect.aCoords.bl, gMatrix);
```

Bottom left corner is where I wish to add the new Circle. After rotation, the bottom left is now the bottom right. But I am still off. As shown, the red circle should be on the corner. It looks like the rotation has not been applied.

qrDecompose gives me something that seems right:

```
{angle: -90, scaleX: 1, scaleY: -1, skewX: 0, skewY: 0, translateX: 6099.626027314769, translateY: 4785.016008065199 }
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't follow all of that but this answer helped me get the position of objects within an `activeSelection` – maybe t will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232485/how-can-i-obtain-the-original-coordinates-from-the-activeobjects-elements-of-a/54233183#54233183

Comment: I'll take a look at it, thanks for your comment

Comment: I've edited and added a screenshot to show the result. Your code made me realize I should of used the rectangle and not its group. But I am still off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was not thinking it the right way. Since I have the rectangle already in hands, I just had to get its own transformation and resolve the corner by my own, the following fixed my issue:

```
       { 
        [...]
        const rect = matchingBay.getObjects()[BAY_RECTANGLE_INX];
        const gMatrix = rect.calcTransformMatrix();
        const decomposed = fabric.util.qrDecompose(gMatrix);
    
        const trans = fabric.util.transformPoint(new fabric.Point((decomposed.scaleX * -rect.width) / 2, (decomposed.scaleY * rect.height) / 2), gMatrix);
        const top = trans.y;
        const left = trans.x;
    
        [...]
      }
```

Since the matrix is bringing the center point of the rectangle, I can get the corner by substracting its width and height and then transforming the coordinates to find out where the matrix puts it.